# How can I get the the "Application used to perform action" with C#

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, file-association

in the windows XP explorer "folder options" dialog is a File type tab. In the file type tab the known filteypes are associated with a program.

When the "Edit File Type" dialog is visible, there are different actions for a file type like open or print. Each of these actions have a property of "Application used to perform action". I need to read out the absolute path and name of the listed software.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the associated programs per file type?

Comment: you can find the applications associated with an extension in the registry, somewhere in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT if I remember well

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into **File Associations**, there's many ways to do it.

MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx

PInvoke, has an shchangenotify(...) has an example in that area of the Registry:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shchangenotify

Also the Related links on the right ->